# Does "hit back" mean "hit back"?

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language

*If the boys at school are still bothering you, you shouldn't be afraid to hit back.*

Is this natural to say? And does "hit back" mean to literally hit someone who has just hit you or just to fight back?

Comment: "fight back" also literally means to hit someone who has just hit you.

Answer (score 1):

It's used both literally and metaphorically.  Sometimes, it can be a mix of both.

In the example you provided, it's a mix, but probably more on the literal side, since it's implied there may actually be physical altercations occurring.

The sentence does sound natural to me.

Comment: I'd say it's more on the metaphorical side.